# Is it possible to host end to end full fledged dynamic web pages over torrents or other P2P protocols?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

Hosting websites over torrent seems like a beautiful idea. It seems that there are already implementations of these. [Planktos](https://github.com/xuset/planktos) and [Bittorret's Maelstrom](https://www.bittorrent.com/blog/2014/12/10/project-maelstrom-the-internet-we-build-next/) have implemented this. But these are not so popular. Apparently Bittorent's Maelstrom in kinda [inactive](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/bittorrent-maelstrom.html)

Is there a way to serve dynamic webpages over torrent or in **any other P2P way**? Is it possible to use decentralized storage and decentralized servers to do server side work and create an end to end, full fledged P2P websites, with full functionality and reasonable efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is doable with any mainstream technology  and I expect if you break it down it is pretty impractical, as (a) you land up distributing your back-end - so it is subject to people dissecting it, modify8ng the results and otherwise stuffing it up.

Likely the best you could do would be a web page with fancy built-in JavaScript to make it interactive and distribute that, but there are significant limits to the functionality you can produce, because you cant practically distribute a back-end - and you still need to a p2p distribution mechanism.

Comment: What about web 3.0 that's what they are claiming to do. Any idea?

Comment: Buzzword bingo does not solve the fundimental problem you have with a p2p model and control of your data.  I dont know who is making that claim about web 3.0, but Its untennable - afaik web 3.0 is the idea of adding more devices, AI, 3d and possibly blockchain/crypto technologies - there is no magic that allows you to control the data while somultaneously relinquishing control of the same to peers.

Comment: "you land up distributing your back-end" Which is exactly what smart contracts running on blockchains do...

Comment: "there is no magic that allows you to control the data while somultaneously relinquishing control of the same to peers. " There is. It is called a blockchain. Did you see the recent surge of NFTs?

Comment: Upvote - @PatrickMevzek I confess that I am not certain if you are poking fun at NFT's and the blockchain or if you are serious.  (Definitely you are technically correct, but blockchain meets exactly none of the criteria the OP requires, and while you can prove ownership of an NFT they don't, AFAIK do anything to prevent other people copying what they represent.)